# Angular FormGroup form control broken on reload

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have the form to choose my image of my logo but when loading the page it is ok, value initiated and the form worke. but when i reload the page or the refresh is empty and broken.

```
<form [formGroup]="paramForm" (ngSubmit)="onSave()">
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Logo</mat-label>
  <mat-select formControlName="fileUrl" >
    <mat-option *ngFor="let file of fileInfos | async" [value]="file.url">
      <img width="50" src='{{file.url}}'> {{file.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<div></div>
<!-- Btn Submit -->
<div class=" d-flex mt-2 mr-3 pb-2 justify-content-end">
  <button type="submit"
          class="btn btn-outline-success mr-3 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
          title="ok">
    <i class="pi pi-check-circle"></i>
  </button>
</div>
    </form>
```

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.paramSiteService.getAllParam().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(paramSite => {
      this.paramBDD = paramSite[0];
    },
    error => console.log(error),
    () => {
      this.fileInfos = this.uploadService.getFiles();
      this.initForm();
    }
    );
  }
    public onSave() {
      if (this.paramForm.invalid) {
        return;
      } else {
        const formValue = this.paramForm.value;
        this.paramSiteService.putParam(this.paramBDD.id, formValue['fileUrl'])
          .subscribe(response => {
              window.location.reload();
            }, error => {
              console.log(error);
            }
          );
      }
    }
  private initForm() {
      this.paramForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      fileUrl: [this.paramBDD.logo.url, Validators.required],
      } );   
  }
```

Works only one time

Answer (score 0):

```
<form *ngIf="paramForm" [formGroup]="paramForm" (ngSubmit)="onSave()">
...
</form>
```

to solve the problem with FormGroup with async.